# Putting 2 divs side by side / Internet Explorer 6/7 float and padding (?) bug fix

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css-float, css

I need to put 2 divs side by side. But what's more important, I want this to display correctly in IE6/7. I have managed to succeed this with Firefox though.
My code:

```
#container{
    padding:10px;
}

#left{
    float:left;
    width:500px;
}

#right{
    width: 300px;
    float:right;
    padding:7px;
    background-color:#F0FCEB;
}

<div id="box"> 
<div id="left">Some content here</div> 
<div id="right">Some content here 2</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

The results are as shown below:

Desired Output (FF Output): 
[image: Desired output]

IE6/7 Output:
[image: IE6/7 output]
How can I get rid of this unnecessary padding in IE, or is there any other method?
Note: I use jQuery and Nifty for jQuery to create rounded corners.

Comment: Knowing the actual HTML content of <div id="right"> might be useful. The screenshot makes it like a difference in padding on the form elements between FF and IE.

Comment: Have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/591539/forms-can-they-be-done-without-tables

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Some content here 2

What's that content? Your example works as-is, so it's something in the content itself that causes the issue.

Does it perhaps include a form, as it looks like on the shot?

<form> has a default top/bottom margin, and how vertical margins collapse is a matter of some confusion and browser differences (it's usually best avoided if possible). So the mini-reset rule:

```
form { margin: 0; }
```

may help.

Answer (score 1):

Dont use a table! i often use an unordered list for long forms. but here 2 divs may work. Make sure that for accessibility you have the Ara: marked up as a `<label>` and you [associate it with the input field](http://www.webrichtlijnen.nl/english/manual/development/production/forms/accessibility/input-fields-and-labels/)

make sure that you have reset the default padding and margin for the items before expressing yours.

```
#box label, #box input {margin:0;padding:0;}
```

Answer (score -3):

Use a `<table>`, they are the best for side-by-side alignments in my experience

Comment: It actually was <table>, however with all the trends around changing tables to divs I though I might follow the crowd and switched it to tabless (as one of the tags for the question implies) :)

Comment: That wouldn't be semantically correct as there's no tabular data to be displayed.

Comment: Why fight the system? Tables are the best when it comes to side by side alignment in web pages. I know it shouldn't be this way, but that's just the way it is. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/591539/forms-can-they-be-done-without-tables