# How do I Align three spans using CSS (no tables)

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have this table in some code;

```
<table>
    <tr><td align="left">One</td><td align="center">Two</td><td align="right">Three</td>
    <tr><td align="left">One</td><td align="center">Two</td><td align="right">Three</td>
    <tr><td align="left">One</td><td align="center">Two</td><td align="right">Three</td>
</table>
```

I would like to not use tables and do the alignment and such all in CSS. I tried;

```
<span style="float:left;">One</span><span style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">Two</span><span style="float:right;">Three</span>
<span style="float:left;">One</span><span style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">Two</span><span style="float:right;">Three</span>
<span style="float:left;">One</span><span style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">Two</span><span style="float:right;">Three</span>
```

Example would be trying to convert this data to CSS to align as the table would;

```
<table>    
<tr><td align="left">Bob</td><td align="center">Dingle</td><td align="right">3923.33</td></tr>
<tr><td align="left">Johann</td><td align="center">Strauss</td><td align="right">33.33</td></tr>
<tr><td align="left">Skip</td><td align="center">Skipperson</td><td align="right">0</td></tr>
</table>
```

But the text in the middle doesn't align correctly as its jagged (different lengths) and so are the left and right values. Seems this is madness and I am leaning towards ["Just Use Tables"](http://giveupandusetables.com/).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/591539/can-form-styling-be-done-without-tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, get your HTML right: Use the correct tags to contain your data. The information you gave isn't really enough for us to ascertain what type of information you're trying to format. *If* it is tabular data, then there's no shame in using tables - its what its meant for.

Now the correct manner to using CSS is *not* to place all of your styles inline like what you are doing. Keep them in a separate CSS file instead, and use selectors to avoid having to repeat yourself so many times.

Here's the solution: http://www.jsfiddle.net/2TDXc/

Oh, and please don't listen to that 'Just Use Table' bullcrap. Really, its better for everyone in the long run.

Comment: The attached links code is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean jagged?  You mean you want `text-align:justify` ?  Or do you mean you're having trouble with the columns being different heights?  If the latter, containing divs might help.  For that matter, try using divs instead of spans or setting `display:block`

Anyway, looking at the CSS templates provided by [Matthew James Taylor](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/perfect-3-column.htm) may help if you mean the latter problem.

Comment: Added some example table layout, jagged text meaning not same length but I need them aligned. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to make use of the `display:inline` and `display:inline-table` css attributes. They're great for forcing any element to sit next to each other on the same line.

```
<div>
    <span style="display:inline-table;padding:2px;">One</span><span style="display:inline-table;padding:2px;">Two</span><span style="display:inline-table;padding:2px;">Three</span><br />
    <span style="display:inline-table;padding:2px;">One</span><span style="display:inline-table;padding:2px;">Two</span><span style="display:inline-table;padding:2px;">Three</span><br />
    <span style="display:inline-table;padding:2px;">One</span><span style="display:inline-table;padding:2px;">Two</span><span style="display:inline-table;padding:2px;">Three</span><br />
</div>
```

As for the jagged-ness, you must realize that your columns do not inherit or share anything from each other like they would in a table, so you'll ultimately have to hardcode a width. It looks like a table might be what you need.