# Laying out "Label - Value" to center without use of tables

Tags: html, css, tabular

So often you will have a number of labels (lets use name, age, colour) and a value for each!

If I placed these In a 2 column 3 row table I could make sure that the values (lets use Steve, 19, Red) all start in the same horizontal position.

And if I wished by having that column left align, and if I also wanted have the label column right aligned. The two columns then would meet nicely in the center of the table..

How could I go about doing this without the use of tables but also not having to set fixed widths!

Comment: And lo! Behold the confusion when you refer to a HTML element when talking about something else completely different. Guys, it's "Label - value pairs", not `label` - `input` pairs for forms I'd presume we're talking about here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to have to resolve yourself to using fixed widths for your labels (if going the pure CSS route.)  Below is the minimum to get what you're trying to accomplish (pulled from [HTML Dog](http://htmldog.com/articles/formlayout/).)

CSS:

```
label {
    clear: left;
    float: left;
    width: 7em; /* or whatever length suits */
    text-align: right;
}
```

HTML:

```
<form>
    <div><label>Item 1</label><input /></div>
    <div><label>Item 2</label><input /></div>
    <div><label>Item 3</label><textarea></textarea></div>
</form>
```

If you absolute don't want fixed widths, then you can use this javascript (with jQuery) and remove the fixed width from the above CSS.  It is worth noting that if you get people with *javascript turned off, this will look awful*!

```
var largestWidth = 0;
$('label').each(
    function() {
        if ($(this).width() > largestWidth) {
            largestWidth = $(this).width();
        }
    });

$('label').each(
    function() {
        $(this).width(largestWidth);
    });
```

I've thrown up a live example on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fRBKE/).

Given the use case that you've cited, I actually think tables is the better way to go, but then I have a [differing opinion on the table/div form debate than most](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/591539/forms-can-they-be-done-without-tables/591763#591763).

Comment: thanks for the input, the reason no width can be set is due to a multi lanauage website. And citing that these seems to be no css solution I will mark yours as the answer as its the closest I can see us getting! thanks

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need javascript then to fix that. I don't believe there is a pure CSS solution to this.

Indeed working with fixed widths can be a problem when working in a multilanguage site where label widths can differ, or where the widths can change depending on browser settings like text size...

Answer (score 0):

I hear what you're saying, but can I remind you that tables are ok for tabular data!

But to do this using pure CSS you could float the label and value left, clear afterwards, and set both elements to display block with 50% width.

Comment: I also hear what you are saying (lol) It just doesn't seem right to use tables for what is one value, its more like a list in my eyes! - I cannot have fixed widths as the labels will have variable widths

Answer (score 0):

You can arrange this alternatively using UL LI lists.

```
<fieldset>

<legend>Sign-up Form</legend>
<form name="signup" action="index.html" method="post">
<ul> 
<li> <label for="name">Name</label>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" size="30" />
</li> 
<li> <label for="email">Email</label>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" size="30" />
</li>



<li> <label for="psw">Password</label>
<input type="text" name="psw" id="psw" size="30" />
</li>



<li> <label for="free">Free Subscrition</label>
<input type="radio" name="subscription" id="free"/>
</li>

<li><label for="submit"></label>
<button type="submit" id="submit">Send</button> </li> 
<ul>
</form>

</fieldset>

css

fieldset ul, fieldset li{
border:0; margin:0; padding:0; list-style:none;
}
fieldset li{
clear:both;
list-style:none;
padding-bottom:10px;
}

fieldset input{
float:left;
}
fieldset label{
width:140px;  // or you give width in % here
float:left;
}
```

Comment: The question specified "not having to set fixed widths" so your `width:140px` isn't going to work.