# CSS Table-Like alignment using no tables? (CSS RelativeLayout)

Tags: css, alignment

Wherever I go on the internet, I am constantly having it beat into me that I should not use Tables. Sadly, I am one of the few programmers who is stubborn enough to still be using them -- I frankly find the alignment and layout features of CSS inadequately powerful for me to, cold turkey, stop using tables. With my personal programmer idiosyncrasies set aside, I would like to try to attack one of my major discontentments with the CSS system:

Let's say I want to have a layout like this:

```
+---+---+
| A | B |
+---+---+
| C | D |
+---+---+
```

In the above example, I would like the widths of A and C to be the same, and the widths of `B` and `D` to remain the same.

I would also like the heights of `A` and `B` to remain locked together, and I would like the heights of `C` and D to stay the same as each other.

To clarify, if any element in a column gets wider, I'd like *all* of the elements in that column to get wider. And if any element in a row gets taller, I, again, want all of the elements in that very same row to get wider as well.

What I have just described is the exact functionality of our old friend, the table. In my opinion, tables are very useful for these kinds of layouts! If I were to attempt something similar to that using CSS layouts, I might get something like this:

```
+-------+---+
|   A   | B |
+---*---*---+
| C |   D   |
+---+-------+
```

Which would very much *NOT* be the kind of layout I am looking for. (`A` and `C` make jagged columns, as opposed to perfect, smooth columns as I would prefer)

To put my problem simply, I could *really* use a way to, using CSS layouts (and NOT predefined widths or heights) align the position of an edge of one CSS box, to the position of an edge of a different CSS box. If CSS supported that one simple feature, I could instantly let go of tables forever, and create layouts beyond even the capabilities of tables! A good, but useless example of such power would be two disconnected boxes on opposite sides of a table, *dynamically* sharing exactly the same height and vertical position as each other.

But unfortunately, in my searches around the internet, the most advanced alignment I've found so far is center, left, and right alignment. All alignment types that are not relative to OTHER elements, making them useless.

All I want is just a way to align HTML elements to OTHER HTML elements without having to use tables!

## EDIT

While picking the tags for this question, I came across a description that pretty much sums it all up:

> Relativelayout: A Layout where the positions of the children can be
>   described in relation to each other or to the parent.

Is there a CSS RelativeLayout? Or am I stuck using tables whenever I want to do this?

I will accept the answer that comes closest to my desired functionality without using predetermined widths or heights (Including the answer "Nothing like that exists" if no one else provides something better).

Comment: People always get this wrong: this is exactly the situation where tables make sense and should be used. There is no sense in trying to mimic their behaviour in pure css. Tables should be avoided in many, many cases for layout purposes, but not always.

Comment: If you really want a table then a table is the answer. However, the question is why do you absolutely want this behavior ? Meaning they are some cases when people think they want a table, but in fact a responsive css solution can be as good or even better.

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/591539/forms-can-they-be-done-without-tables

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is possible to display elements as tables that aren't semantically tables, only using CSS. Using the `display` property, you can imitate tables while you have divs in your markup. [Check this article](http://www.onenaught.com/posts/201/use-css-displaytable-for-layout).

Depending on what you want to achieve, there are some alternative options. If you only want the two rows in each column stick to the width of the column, you should try putting the rows inside the column tag instead of doing the opposite. This is working without predefined dimensions.

Also, if the heights are set the same for each cell in a row you could simply float them to left, and set container width to the sum of row width. This only works with predefined dimensions.

CSS

```
div.c
{
    width: 100%;
}

div.c>div:nth-child(2n-1)
{
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
    background: blue;
}

div.c>div:nth-child(2n)
{
    width: 75%;
    float: left;
    background: yellow;
}
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kdani3/DbRuV/

A more complex example: http://jsfiddle.net/kdani3/DbRuV/1/

I think it's really simple, even simpler than using a table layout.

Also, I really recommend you to take a look at CSS grid frameworks, like [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/). That's definitely worth a look.

Comment: One of the benefit of the table is to not have to specify width, as the OP said that a column increase it size (on every row) if needed (without having to specify a width). Your example doesn't provide this essential table feature.

Comment: True. Thats why I recommended Bootstrap and the `display: table;`. However, in most cases my example is enough. If you can attach predefined dimensions at least at a few elements, there is a solution. If you can't, `display:table;` is the answer.

Comment: Of course, as you mentioned above, in case of actual tables, using table tag is the semantically correct solution. Tables should look like tables, and should be semantic in markup. That's why I don't prefer layouts that copy table layout. Tables should look like tables, layout shouldn't. Of course, there are some rare cases, when a table-ish layout looks better, in these cases I recommend the `display` property.

Comment: Hello! Your answer is clever, in that in certain circumstances, I can, indeed, make the columns the parents, instead of the rows. However, there are certain situations where I need *both* to be aligned. Sadly, such solutions will not work :( Using pre-determined widths is also no option. Using Twitter Bootstrap is interesting, although I was wondering if there is something more powerful than being restricted to 12 predetermined columns. Upvoted your answer, though, as it is informative

Comment: How about `display` propertys? Please check the article I've refered to in my answer. I think using the display property is a good solution for your problem.

Comment: Very cool -- I will accept your answer! If you add a note in bold that says the answer was accepted for the display:table, bit, that would be very helpful to others also wondering the same thing

Comment: Ok. Thanks for feedback. I've posted and edit to emphasize the `display` property part. Do you think it is okay?

Comment: This is a good solution but sadly: The values "inline-table", "table" .... are not supported in IE7 and earlier. IE8 requires a !DOCTYPE. IE9 supports the values.

Answer (score 4):

I think for using pure CSS, with no `Width`, and no using `table` you can use [Flex Layout](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/)

This is the code

**HTML**

```
<section class="flexrow">
    <div class='item'>1asdf</div>
    <div class='item'>2</div>
</section>
<section class="flexrow">
    <div class='item'>1</div>
    <div class='item'>2</div>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
.flexrow {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -ms-flex;
    display: -o-flex;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
    -moz-justify-content: space-between;
    -ms-justify-content: space-between;
    -o-justify-content: space-between;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -moz-align-items: center;
    -ms-align-items: center;
    -o-align-items: center;
    -webkit-flex: none;
    -moz-flex: none;
    -ms-flex: none;
    -o-flex: none;
}
.item {
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    -moz-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex: 1;
    -o-flex: 1;
    margin: auto 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

Here is the [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VGjVk/)

Comment: Your answer sounds promising! I tried viewing your example in a nightly build of firefox, and it did not work (flex rows appear to simply be more like columns directly on top of each other). It continued to not work even after changing the div-flexrow in your example to a section-flexrow. Would you mind letting me know what browser you are using, so that I may see the example first hand? Thankyou!

Comment: I am using Google Chrome, I have posted my example in jsfiddle, and the link is above

Comment: Ah! Running your example in Chrome has worked now. Unfortunately, I modified it (to have more f's, and to have a <br/> tag before the last five or so f's). It does not maintain the same column size (or row size for that matter) as its siblings int he same columns/rows. While this is an interesting layout strategy, if it cannot maintain alignment dynamically, I am not sure that it will do the same trick as a table. My problems are evidenced here: http://i.imgur.com/Jf5T6j3.png