# Divide one PHP echo into 3 columns

Tags: php, css

I have managed to put this code together.

```
$sql = "
SELECT
        inbox.ReceivingDateTime,
    namnlista.namn AS SenderNumber, inbox.Text
FROM
inbox
INNER JOIN
namnlista
ON
inbox.SenderNumber = namnlista.SenderNumber";



$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

  echo 

$row["ReceivingDateTime"],

$row["SenderNumber"],

$row["Text"],"<br>";
}
} else {
echo "0 results";
}

mysqli_close($conn);
```

and it shows my info fine on my page but of course like this

```
ReceivingDateTimeSenderNumberText
```

And I want to make it look like this (using my index.css file)

```
ReceivingDateTime     SenderNumber                  Text
```

I've tried adding stuff into the echo line but every time I do my page stops working so I am doing something wrong...

I've managed to add this, and make a table I guess?

```
echo 

"<table> <tr> <td>"

.$row["ReceivingDateTime"]."</td>".

"<td>". $row["SenderNumber"]."</td>".

"<td>".$row["Text"]."</td></tr></table>";
```

But still it doesnt look good, I can use padding in CSS but what should I use to make the 3 columns all start at selected points?

Now the next column starts after the same amount of empty space regardless of the length of the previous column and that is not good.

[image]

Comment: The text for each column entry needs to be placed in a containing HTML element which can then be styled using CSS. Creating a table in HTML and putting text inside `<td>` elements works well. Alternatives, such as pre-formatted monospaced text or CSS only solutions ([e.g. this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16031559/5217142)) also exist.

Comment: Please provide the HTML sent to the browser for the image above - the image itself does not help debugging. You can view and then copy the HTML by  right clicking the page in a web browser and selecting "view source". Also include the CSS used to style the elements in the image. thx

Comment: I managed to solve this with html tables and css styling to set width to the columns. Thanks for all the answers!

Answer (score 0):

Only concatenate a space (o whatever) after echo. See this example. Concatenation of strings in PHP are with dot.

```
$sql = "
    SELECT
            inbox.ReceivingDateTime,
        namnlista.namn AS SenderNumber, inbox.Text
    FROM
    inbox
    INNER JOIN
    namnlista
    ON
    inbox.SenderNumber = namnlista.SenderNumber";



    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

      echo 

    $row["ReceivingDateTime"]." ", //here

    $row["SenderNumber"]." ",// and here

    $row["Text"],"<br>";
    }
    } else {
    echo "0 results";
    }

    mysqli_close($conn);
```

Comment: THanks for the answer, but adding a space would make it look real funny since SenderNumber is never the same length (a name)? Then Text would just start one space after the SenderNumber.

Answer (score 0):

The absolute simplest way to get your data into columns would be to use

```
echo "<pre>" . $row["ReceivingDateTime"] . "\t" . $row["SenderNumber"] . "\t" . $row["Text"] . "</pre><br>";
```

This doesn't give you much structure in the html.  Semantically a table is probably more appropriate but this is quick and dirty.

The `<pre>` tag in html means preserve whitespace, and the `\t` is a special character representing a tab.

Answer (score -1):

Right, similar to what Christian said, you can concatenate a space after each term. But the question indicated that you wanted columns. If that's the case, you can also user '\t' for a tabbed effect.

Comment: HTML renders a tab outside a `<pre>` block the same as any block of white space: a single space.